# GROUP BY with multiple fields (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table with 3 columns:

**History**:

```
ID  |  xDate  |  xUser
```

I would like to return the `ID`, `xDate` and `xUser` for the last `xDate` of each `ID`.

This is what I've got:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Last = Max(xDate)
FROM 
    History
GROUP BY 
    ID
ORDER BY 
    Last DESC
```

As soon as I add the `xUser` to the `SELECT`, it stops working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 ID  |  xDate  |  xUser  
 01     2014-1  Joe  
 01     2014-2  Bob  
 01     2014-3  Tom  
 02     2014-1  Joe  
 02     2014-2  Bob  
 02     2014-3  Tom
```

Desired results:

```
 ID  |  xDate  |  xUser  
 01     2014-3  Tom  
 02     2014-3  Tom
```

Comment: Well, which xUser do you want? If you have two rows with ID = 5, and on one row xUser = foo and on another row xUser = bar, how do you expect SQL Server to pick which one you want? Show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: (PS if you're looking to get the xUser associated with the row that has the max date, this is cumbersome to solve in SQL Server 2000 - it involves an expensive self-join and relies on xDate to be unique (at least per user).) If you don't care which xUser you get, then just use MIN(xUser) or MAX(xUser) - though at that point I'd wonder what is the point of including it. In any case, would you care to join us in this century with a more modern version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2000 is what I have to work with. This is not my choice.

Comment: I'd like the xUser in the same record at the MAX(xDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-query for each ID, what is the last date...  Then from that, re-join to your history table on BOTH components to get the name corresponding to that ID

```
SELECT 
      H2.ID, 
      H2.xDate,
      H2.Name
   FROM 
      ( select ID, max(xDate) ThisDate
           from History
            Where xdate > '2014-09-01'
           group by ID ) PreCheck
         JOIN History H2
            on PreCheck.ID = H2.ID
           AND PreCheck.ThisDate = H2.xDate
   ORDER BY 
      H2.xDate DESC
```

Your issue will be if you have multiple entries on a given date unless the dates are really a full date/time for most recent entry.

Also, it would be best to have an index on  your table on (ID, xDate)

Comment: It's a full datetime, so this should work near all the time. I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: It works! but with the amount of rows in this table, it's crazy slow. Looks like the best I can do with the tools. Thanks again.

Comment: @Stephen, If you know all the IDs will have an entry within the last day or so, you could add a WHERE clause to the inner "PreCheck" query, such as WHERE xDate > '2014-09-01' so it doesn't have to plow through year(s) of history.  Even if going back say one week's worth of ID #s is the important element to consider.

Comment: I set the check to > 2 hours ago, and it still took 60sec+ to run. I'll try again here and see if it's making a difference.

Comment: I added the 'WHERE xDate >' right before the 'ORDER BY' as well and it runs like a dream (.5 sec for a day, 10 sec for a month), but only when both querys have the check. Odd. Either way, this is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @stephen, you should have only needed the where on the (query within parens).. Not outside before the order by area.